# Why the content script execution does not continue after 2 reloads?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I've been making an extension to always win in www.frikitrivial.com. All the mechanics are in the content script file, it has to reload the page each time the url of the tab is equal to "http://www.frikitrivial.com/end.php", but after doing that 2 times, it stops, I means, the content script does not execute anymore. I have checked this writing a console.log() at the beginning of the script.

Thanks.

This is the code from the content script file (you can ignore the most of it).

```js
console.log( "Iniciando partida..." )


let question, answers, _answers

if( location.href !==  "http://www.frikitrivial.com/end.php" ){
    question = document.querySelectorAll("div.question")[0].textContent
    answers = []
    _answers = document.querySelectorAll("a.answer")
    
    document.querySelectorAll("a.answer").forEach( e => answers.push( e.textContent ) )
}


function click( s ) {
    let c
    for( let i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        if( s === _answers[i].textContent ) {
            c = _answers[i]
        }
    }
    console.log( "El siguiente elemento va a ser clickado..." )
    console.log( c )
    c.click()
}

chrome.storage.sync.get(["lastClicked"], function(result){
    if( result.lastClicked ) {
        console.log( "Leido lastClicked..." )
        if( location.href === "http://www.frikitrivial.com/end.php" ) { // manejamos fallo
            console.log( "Manejando fallo de pregunta..." )
            chrome.storage.sync.set({
                [result.lastClicked.question]: {
                    question: result.lastClicked.question,
                    answers: result.lastClicked.answers.shift(),
                    answered: false
                }
            }, () => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: "https://www.frikitrivial.com/game.php"}))
        } else { // actualizamos el estado de la ultima pregunta respondida
            if( !result.lastClicked.answered ){
                console.log( "Manejando lastClicked not answered..." )
                chrome.storage.sync.set({
                    [result.lastClicked.question]: {
                        question: result.lastClicked.question,
                        answers: result.lastClicked.answers,
                        answered: true
                    }
                }, answerNewQuestion)
            } else {
                console.log( "Manejando lastClicked answered..." )
                answerNewQuestion()
            }
        }
    } else {
        answerNewQuestion()
    }
})

function answerNewQuestion() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get([question], function(result){
        if( result.question ) { // si ya hemos intentado responder esta pregunta alguna vez
            if( result.question.answered ) {
                chrome.storage.sync.set( {
                    [result.question]: {
                        question: result.question.question,
                        answers: result.question.answers,
                        answered: result.question.answered
                    }
                }, () => click( result.question.answers[0] ) )
            } else {
                chrome.storage.sync.set( {
                    lastClicked: {
                        question: result.question.question,
                        answers: result.question.answers,
                        answered: result.question.answered
                    }
                }, () => click( result.question.answers[0] ) )
            }
        } else {
            chrome.storage.sync.set( {
                [question]: {
                    question: question,
                    answers: answers,
                    answered: false
                }
            }, function( result ){
                chrome.storage.sync.set( {
                    lastClicked: {
                        question: question,
                        answers: answers,
                        answered: false
                    }
                }, () => click( answers[0] ) )
            })
        }
    })  
}
```

And here is the manifest.json!

```
{
"name": "Getting Started Example",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab", 
    "declarativeContent", 
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["http://www.frikitrivial.com/game.php*", "http://www.frikitrivial.com/end.php"],
    "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
],
"manifest_version": 2
```

}

Comment: I like to start debugging this sort of problem by commenting out almost the entire file except for the console.log statement and then running it, just to verify for certain that the problem has nothing to do with the content of the file itself.

Comment: You didn't show your manifest.json so I have to guess what happens on the third time. 1) Maybe the URL is different, which doesn't match `"matches"` in manifest.json. 2) Maybe the page is using "soft" navigation via History API or by changing the hash (URL fragment)

Comment: I'm going to add it wait!